# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING Retrofit Android

Tags: android, retrofit

Json Data

```
[
  {
    "date": "25-09-2016",
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "57e601bbf2a9d92a445ef8a3"
    },
    "createdAt": "2016-09-24 10:01:55 +0530",
    "horoscope": [
      {
        "date": "25-09-2016",
        "sunsign": "aries",
        "horoscope": "Testing.."
      },
      {
        "date": "25-09-2016",
        "sunsign": "taurus",
        "horoscope": "Testing.."
      },
      {
        "date": "25-09-2016",
        "sunsign": "pisces",
        "horoscope": "Testing.."
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

HoroscopeModel.java:

```
public class HoroscopeModel {

    private Date date;
    private Date createdAt;
    private List<HoroscopeModel> horoscope;

    public List<HoroscopeModel> getHoroscope() {
        return horoscope;
    }

    public void setHoroscope(List<HoroscopeModel> horoscope) {
        this.horoscope = horoscope;
    }


    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public List<HoroscopeModel> getHoroscopeList() {
        return horoscope;
    }

    public void setHoroscopeList(List<HoroscopeModel> horoscopeList) {
        this.horoscope = horoscopeList;
    }
}
```

Horoscope.java

```
public class Horoscope {

    Date date;
    String sunshine;
    String horoscope;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getSunShine() {
        return sunshine;
    }

    public void setSunShine(String sunShine) {
        this.sunshine = sunShine;
    }

    public String getHoroscope() {
        return horoscope;
    }

    public void setHoroscope(String horoscope) {
        horoscope = horoscope;
    }
}
```

ApiInterface.java

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("/get_horoscope")
    Call<List<HoroscopeModel>> getHoroscope();
}
```

Retrofit:

```
private void setupRestClient() {
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    client.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_URL)
            .client(client.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(getGson()))
            .build();

    REST_CLIENT = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
}

private Gson getGson() {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer());
    builder.setPrettyPrinting();
    return builder.create();
}
```

DateDeserializer.java

```
public class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    private static final String TAG = "DateDeserializer";
    private static final String[] DATE_FORMATS = new String[]{
            "yyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z",//2016-09-24 08:18:56 +0530
            "dd-MM-yyyy"
    };

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type typeOF,
                            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        for (String format : DATE_FORMATS) {
            try {
                return new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US).parse(jsonElement.getAsString());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
            }
        }
        throw new JsonParseException("Unparseable date: \"" + jsonElement.getAsString()
                + "\". Supported formats: " + Arrays.toString(DATE_FORMATS));
    }
}
```

With everything perfectly set up it throws an error saying `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 183 path $[0].horoscope[0].horoscope` , Please let me know is there any mistake in my code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is quite self-explanatory.

`$[0].horoscope[0].horoscope` is a `String`, but you're trying to deserialize it into a `List`.

That's because in `HoroscopeModel` you're defining `horoscope` as type of `List<HoroscopeModel>`, instead of `List<Horoscope>`.

*Gson* is trying to deserialize the value of `horoscope` (a `String`) into the `horoscope` field of `HoroscopeModel` (a `List`) instead of the `horoscope` field of `Horoscope` (a `String`).

In `HoroscopeModel`, change to following field:

```
private List<HoroscopeModel> horoscope;
```

To this:

```
private List<Horoscope> horoscope;
```

(and don't forget to modify the corresponding methods also)

Answer (score 0):

Gosn doesn't convert your string to Date directly it reuires to define specific format as follows.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
.create();
```

So you should use String in place of Date wherever used as follows

```
public class Horoscope {

    String date
```

and

```
public class HoroscopeModel {

    private String date;
    private String createdAt;
```

Comment: I hope this is not the problem, I already have date DateDeserializer attached to Gson, Please have a look at my updated question.